# how to display items in listbox

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, drop-down-menu

How to display list of items in list box while choose a particular item in dropdown list.

example: thiru is a developer he done some modules. 
    in dropdown list has a list of developers while choose thiru in this list i want        to display a what are all the modules completed by thiru that can be listed in listbox

I am using Visual Studio 2008,C# with ASP.Net

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't specific enough, for example you don't mention the language or list box class you are using. And what does thiru have to do with anything? Did you just talk about yourself in the third person?

Comment: WinForm, WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: Thiru edit your question with the above information

Comment: I have edited the question as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

On the listbox databind your items to a datasource and add a parameter with the value from you drop down list.

This is roughly what you need to do.

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="listDataSource" 
        DataTextField="Field" DataValueField="Field"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="listDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXX %>" 
            SelectCommand=
                "SELECT [Field] FROM [LisotOfModules] WHERE ([DevID] = @DevID)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="DevID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

   </div>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="ddlDatasource" DataTextField="DevID" 
        DataValueField="DevID">
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ddlDatasource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXX %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [DevID] FROM [Developers]">
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data source is just a List or similar, you can simply do the following:

```
myListBox.DataSource = myDataSource;
myListBox.DataBind();
```

If your datasource is a class or list of classes, you need to specify which property to display and which to set as the value.

As above:

```
myListBox.DataSource = myDataSource;
myListBox.DataTextField = "MyPropertyNameOnMyClass"; //This will be displayed
myListBox.DataValueField = "MyValuePropertyOnMyClass";
myListBox.DataBind();
```